# Object oriented programming with Tkinter: how to return control to main

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm trying to translate my OOP and Java knowledge to self-taught Python. I am creating an app that uses Tkinter and a database. I have the database connection in a class, and the Tkinter controls in a class. I'd like the main class to control the database connection and handling. I'm envisioning that my program will (in pseudocode):

in main

- execute db_class which creates the database, tables, and populates the data
- call the tkinter class which opens the GUI, loads the first frame, displays widgets,
  handles user-input, and has the action listener (button)
  - on button click, I'd like to pass the control back to main with the user
  input
  back to main
- main calls the database class(es) again to fetch results from database
- main then stores said results in an array of objects
- main passes said results back to the Tkinter class for display in the GUI (frame 2)

The above plan seems to me to be a better way to modularize code (less spaghetti code):

main --> db_handeling --> main -->Tkinter --> main --> db_handling --> main -->
object_creation --> main -->Tkinter

than:

main --> db_handeling --> main -->Tkinter --> db_handling --> object_creation --> Tkinter --> main

What is the actual best way/Pythonic way to do organize this program? Should I just have the Tkinter in the main class rather than as a separate class? I'm currently stuck because I can't figure out how to pass control back to main upon button click:

```
class TkinterInterface:
    ....
    search = tk.Button(
            self.frame1,
            text="Fetch!",
            font=("TkTextFont", 12),
            fg="black",
            cursor="hand2",
            activeforeground=self.bg_color,
            command=lambda: [self.get_activities_selection(listbox), #pass_back_to_main]
```

Classes:

- main
- db_connection and/or db_handler (these could be two separate or combined)
- object_class
- Tkinter_class

Comment: What does *control* mean? I have no java experience, but along my python research I've learned that java also have threads. Despite the fact that java dose not suffer under the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). The way you organize your project and your business logic is not a thing python gives you *one obvious way* to do so, rather it offers you all the possibilities you could imagine, since there seems no one has the golden key for everything and every decision is a tradeoff.

Comment: Typically, you'll define a set of callbacks to user input events instead of the top-down `main` method that you're used to.